# bool expression seems logical but doesn't work

Tags: c, while-loop, boolean-expression

I'm reading 3 integers in my C program and storing them in an `int *[]`. While reading the 3rd `int` however, I want to compare it to the previous 2 and if it's greater than both of them the program ends, if it isn't the program will keep on reading the 3rd. input until it satisfies the condition in the `while` loop.

My issue is, although the bool expression seems logical (to me at least) and the values I enter are successfully stored in the array, why does it always skip the `while` loop?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) { // Stelios Papamichail 4020
    int *sides[3];
    int i;
    for(i=0; i < 3; i++) {
        if(i == 2) {// third side
            scanf(" %d",&sides[i]);
            while((sides[i] < sides[i-1]) && (sides[i] < sides[i-2])) {
                scanf(" %d",&sides[i]);
            }
        } else {
            scanf(" %d",&sides[i]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `!((c > a) && (c > b))` is equivalent to `((c <= a) || (c <= b))`, not to `((c < a) && (c < b))`

Comment: A `int *[]` is not an array of integers... but an array of **pointers to integers**.  You must drop the `*` in your declaration.

Comment: It looks like you forgot to enable a good set of warnings.  For GCC, I recommend `-Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings` as a minimum; consider also `-Wpedantic -Warray-bounds` for identifying some other common mistakes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main problem in your code is, it invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

To elaborate, in your code, by saying

```
 int *sides[3];
```

you are defining an array of 3 `int *`s (array of 3 pointers to integer), whereas, what you need is an array of 3 `int`s. Change it to

```
int sides[3];
```

That said, based on your requirement, the `&&` in the `while` condition should be `||`, if you want to check for the third input to be the smallest.

Comment: Our teacher requested to use  an array of int pointers so i must use that. Is it wrong? I changed it earlier to an int array just out of curiosity and that didn't work either

Comment: @SteliosPapamichail I dont see why'd you need an array of pointers. However, I updated my answer a bit, check if it works.

Comment: it's probably used later on in the exercise :) . Your edit solved it and i see why i should have used `||` instead of `&&`. My bad and thanks for the help

Comment: @SteliosPapamichail, an array of pointers is being filled with integer values.  Nothing wrong, but as they are integers, you must not consider them as pointers.  I don't fully understand the reasons your teacher argue to use pointers instead of integers, but you'll run into trouble and run into problems by using the wrong type to operate with numbers.  Pointers and numbers, are comparable, and you can do arithmetic with them.  But arithmetic and comparison rules differ between pointers and integers and you'll run into trouble for sure in the future.

Comment: @SouravGhosh, why do you say this code invokes Undefined Behaviour?  can you be more specific?

Comment: @LuisColorado Sure, check the types, what is type of `side[i]`? What would be the type of `&sides[i]`? and what `scanf()` expects as argument to `%d`? This type mismatch causes the UB. Better? :)

Comment: yes... I've checked... `%d` says to read a decimal ascii value and put the result in the place pointed to by the pointer.  I don't see a problem there.  You can initialise a pointer with an absolute address there, and as the pointer size is greater or equal than the integer size, I don't fully see the U.B. at all.  Possible to get a meaningles value as a pointer, but as he is using the data as integer, no U.B. results.

Comment: @LuisColorado __(1)__ `and as the pointer size is greater or equal than the integer size` - that's your assumption, it's not mandated in the standard. __(2)__ the spec mentions any type mismatch as UB. Check `C11`, chapter §7.21.6.2/P10. __(3)__ there is nothing called "fully UB"/ "partially UB". It is either a defined behavior, implementation defined behavior or undefined. In this case, spec is explicit about the UB.

Comment: Not, it is not.... but tell me just one architecture that has integer larger than address types... I'm not sure about your assertion anyway... I've not read the standard recently, probably you can illustrate better than me on this point.  I cannot believe your assertion of `any type mismatch as UB`.  Does that mean that storing an `int` into a `long` to be a U.B?  (is a type mismatch, i'm afraid the standard doesn't speak so vaguely as to say _any type mismatch is a U.B._)

Comment: @LuisColorado , yes, it would be UB. `long` and  `int` are **not** compatible types. That is why there are two seperate conversion specifiers, `%id` for `long` and `%d` for `int`. Mixing them up is not allowed and UB.

Comment: @LuisColorado the exact quote: `Unless assignment suppression was indicated by a *, the
result of the conversion is placed in the object pointed to by the first argument following
the format argument that has not already received a conversion result. If this object
does not have an appropriate type, or if the result of the conversion cannot be represented
in the object, the behavior is undefined.`

Answer (score 1):

You say:

> I'm reading 3 integers in my C program and storing them in an int *[]. While reading the 3rd int however, I want to compare it to the previous 2 and if it's greater than both of them the program ends, if it isn't the program will keep on reading the 3rd. input until it satisfies the condition in the while loop.

well, an `int` is not the same as a pointer.  An `int` allows you to do integer arithmetic, while an `int *` allows you to do pointer arithmetic.  (the pointer stores the memory address of an `int` variable, and as such, when you increment it, it moves its value to the *next* address, which is not the same as adding one ---because an `int` needs more than one byte to fit in memory)  You can use `int *` in your program (as you say in the comments, your teacher has indicated that) but that's like making an omelette but using apples instead of eggs (well, they are both round, but the result is not the same).  I cannot guess the reason your teacher asked you to use `int *`, but that gives me warnings from the compiler, advising me of the risk of doing this (compiler is CLANG, on FreeBSD)

> My issue is, although the bool expression seems logical (to me at least) and the values I enter are successfully stored in the array, why does it always skip the while loop?

Well, that depends on what you try to check.  The first thing on this is that you are say in the code is *compare the last input number with the earlier ones, and if it is greater than or equal than any of them, then input the third number again*.  That's correct if that is what you want, but I cannot guess also what is the purpose of doing such a test, so the only thing I can conclude is that the test is not well written (and mainly because of what I'm going to say next).

The third comment about your program is:

If you need to check the last value against the previous ones, why don't do that outside of the loop.  Doing so not only allows your code to look simpler, but also eliminates the need of the `if (i == 2)` test (you don't need to use `i` at all in your code, just write:

```
    for(i=0; i < 3; i++) {
        scanf("%d",&sides[i]); /* you don't need the space before %d */
    }
    while((sides[2] < sides[1]) && (sides[2] < sides[0])) {
        scanf("%d",&sides[2]);
    }
```

Last, you say in a comment that changing `int *sides[3]` to just `int sides[3]` makes compilation fail.  I've tried and just eliminating that `*` just eliminates three warnings I get from your code compilation.  Cannot guess why do you say it doesn't compile with that elimination.

## NOTE

Your code seems to try to check if the three sides of a triangle allow you to build one.  If that's is true, the correct test is for the third triangle to be *greater than the difference of the previous sides **and** less than the sum of the previous sides*, and this is not what you have written above.  A valid test should be:

```
#define ABS(expr) ((expr) < 0 ? -(expr) : (expr))

while (sides[2] >= sides[1] + sides[0] || sides[2] <= ABS(sides[1] - sides[0])) {
    scanf("%d", &sides[2]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An array go given size is declared with:

```
int sides[3];
```

while an array of unknown size (a pointer basically) is declared with:

```
int* sides;//you should use malloc to allocate the array memory at run time.
```

Using

int* sides[3];

you are declaring an array of pointers.

Your final code should look like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) { // Stelios Papamichail 4020
    int sides[3];
    int i;
    for(i=0; i < 3; i++) {
        if(i == 2) {// third side
            printf("%d %d %d\n", sides[i], sides[i-1], sides[i-2]);

            scanf(" %d",&sides[i]);
            while((sides[i] < sides[i-1]) && (sides[i] < sides[i-2])) {
                printf("%d %d %d\n", sides[i-2], sides[i-1], sides[i]);
                scanf(" %d",&sides[i]);
            }
        } else {
            printf("%d %d %d\n", sides[i-2], sides[i-1], sides[i]);
            scanf(" %d",&sides[i]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I added some prints to understand what's going on.